# Not able to fill the textboxes in frameset. ? how can i do that

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function load()
    {
      var the_form = parent.document.frames['myFrame'].document.forms['form1'];
       var source = the_form.elements['Login1_UserName'];
         var target = the_form.elements['Login1_Password'];
        alert('');
          }
 </script>
  </head>

 <frameset>
   <frame name="myFrame" src="http://xyz.com/" onload="load()" />
 </frameset>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your frame is on a different domain. Access to frames on different domains (or ports, or protocols) is prohibited by the [Same Origin Policy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: I can access if its a normal java script and the web page is our own companys web page. but its made by third party

Comment: @Nivids yup, that's the  point of the Same Origin Policy. There's no easy workaround for it if you don't control the third party web site

Comment: but if we fire the script on the address bar it works how its possible with iframe it wont work